# vs 2013 update 5 crash after open projects, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After open my project in visual studio 2013, I have several errors, regarding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe component.

Event data from event viewer

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe 
12.0.21005.1 
524fa105 
ntdll.dll 
6.1.7601.18939 
55afd843 
c0000005 
00039dde 
2a24 
01d0da7d260d9944 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll 
63da8de8-4670-11e5-8a9c-0019999f62f2
```

[here the .mdmp file](http://1drv.ms/1WEtzVc)

I found this in ActivityLog.xml

> 771
>       2015/08/19 12:46:04.829
>       Error
>       Extension Manager
>       Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop' is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK...
>       C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\

VS version is

> Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
>   Versione 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
>   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Versione 4.6.00081

My OS is Windows 7 Pro x64, SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by installing an update to Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript. After that it worked fine.

You can go to Tools -> Extensions and Update -> Updates.
Look for Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript and update to the latest version.